# mvc3 transferring values from page 1 to page 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I got 2 pages; page 1 and page 2 and i would like to transfer data from page 1 to 2. What I have in Page 1 is a link inside a foreach statement that link will always have a unique value as shown here

```
         page 1

        foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
        {
  @Html.ActionLink("Report", "model", "cars", new { id= item.MyValue }, new { @style = "color:#980000" })
         }
```

As you can tell from the foreach there are many links inside and each link will have a unique number **(MyValue)** . That number MyValue will also correspond to a database record and upon users clicking a link i would like to open a new page **cars/model** that matches MyValue==database-record-number . I just do not know how to carry a value from page 1 to page 2. This is what I have on page 2

```
    page 2
    public ActionResult model(int id)
    {
      // how can I transfer MyValue to the id field here


        var threader = (from s in db.database where s.ModelID == id select s).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(threader);
    }
```

Comment: When you debug the program, is the id variable not set? Your code looks fine to me. the link that should be printed to page 1 is `url/report/model/<id>`, is that not what is happening? Is your `routes.config` setup to handle that parameter?

Comment: perfect that was the issue my route,config has been changed and it did not take an ID parameter all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `routes.config` to handle the parameter.